# How to save a generic custom object to UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

This is my generic class:

```
open class SMState<T: Hashable>: NSObject, NSCoding {
    open var value: T

    open var didEnter: ( (_ state: SMState<T>) -> Void)?
    open var didExit:  ( (_ state: SMState<T>) -> Void)?

    public init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    convenience required public init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        let value = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "value") as! T

        self.init(value)
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(value, forKey: "value")
    }
}
```

Then I want to do this:

```
    let stateEncodeData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: currentState)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(stateEncodeData, forKey: "state")
```

In my case `currentState` is of type `SMState<SomeEnum>.`

But when I call `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData`, Xcode (9 beta 5) shows a message in purple saying:

```
Attempting to archive generic Swift class 'StepUp.SMState<StepUp.RoutineViewController.RoutineState>' with mangled runtime name '_TtGC6StepUp7SMStateOCS_21RoutineViewController12RoutineState_'. Runtime names for generic classes are unstable and may change in the future, leading to non-decodable data.
```

I am not exactly sure what it tries to say. Is not possible to save a generic object ?

Is there any other way to save a generic custom object ?

`edit`:

Even if I use `AnyHashable` instead of generics I get the same error on runtime when calling `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData`:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: : unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Make your struct conform to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding.

Comment: Try to constraint `T` to `NSCoding`?

Comment: @Sweeper: T is an enum, I can't constraint it to NSCoding, because is of "non-class type"

Comment: If you want to make an enum as T, I suggest you can change all the T to AnyHashable. AnyHashable can suit any kinds of enums, which I think can solve your problem. Use AnyHashable, you can delete the Generic, and then save the object to UserDefaults

Comment: @pluto: can u provide an example, it will be easier for me to understand

Comment: OK， I will write as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make the generic class adopt `NSCoding` and the generic type `T` is going to be encoded and decoded then `T` **must be one of the property list compliant types**.

Property list compliant types are `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate` and `NSData`

---

A possible solution is to create a protocol `PropertyListable` and extend all Swift equivalents of the property list compliant types to that protocol

The protocol requirements are

- An **`associated type`**.
- A computed property **`propertyListRepresentation`** to convert the value to a property list compliant type.
- An initializer **`init(propertyList`** to do the contrary.

---

```
public protocol PropertyListable {
    associatedtype PropertyListType
    var propertyListRepresentation : PropertyListType { get }
    init(propertyList : PropertyListType)
}
```

Here are exemplary implementations for `String` and `Int`.

```
extension String : PropertyListable {
    public typealias PropertyListType = String
    public var propertyListRepresentation : PropertyListType { return self }
    public init(propertyList: PropertyListType) { self.init(stringLiteral: propertyList) }
}

extension Int : PropertyListable {
    public typealias PropertyListType = Int
    public var propertyListRepresentation : PropertyListType { return self }
    public init(propertyList: PropertyListType) { self.init(propertyList) }
}
```

Lets declare a sample enum and adopt `PropertyListable`

```
enum Foo : Int, PropertyListable {
    public typealias PropertyListType = Int

    case north, east, south, west

    public var propertyListRepresentation : PropertyListType { return self.rawValue }
    public init(propertyList: PropertyListType) {
        self.init(rawValue:  propertyList)!
    }
}
```

Finally replace your generic class with

```
open class SMState<T: PropertyListable>: NSObject, NSCoding {
    open var value: T

    open var didEnter: ( (_ state: SMState<T>) -> Void)?
    open var didExit:  ( (_ state: SMState<T>) -> Void)?

    public init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    convenience required public init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        let value = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "value") as! T.PropertyListType
        self.init(T(propertyList: value))
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(value.propertyListRepresentation, forKey: "value")
    }
}
```

---

With this implementation you can create an instance and archive it

```
let currentState = SMState<Foo>(Foo.north)
let stateEncodeData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: currentState)
```

and unarchive it again

```
let restoredState = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: stateEncodeData) as! SMState<Foo>
print(restoredState.value)
```

---

The whole solution seems to be cumbersome but you have to fulfill the restriction that `NSCoding` requires property list compliant types. If you don't need a custom type like an `enum` the implementation is much easier (and shorter).

Comment: It's not clear for me what propertyListRepresentation should do ?

Comment: In all mentioned classes in the answer it's supposed to `return self`. In case of the enum return the (property list compliant) raw value. The crucial part of your class is `NSCoder`. The generic type must be supported by `NSCoder`.

Comment: I still get the same error on runtime. And on compile time still getting the purple warning specified in my question.

Comment: I updated the answer. The solution to consider also enums is a bit extensive but it works.

Comment: The bottleneck is the effort to make `NSCoding` generic.

Comment: Yep, it's good knowledge what u wrote here, I will award the bounty when it will be eligible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
open class SMState: NSObject, NSCoding {
    open var value: AnyHashable

    open var didEnter: ( (_ state: SMState) -> Void)?
    open var didExit:  ( (_ state: SMState) -> Void)?

    public init(_ value: AnyHashable) {
        self.value = value
    }

    convenience required public init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        let value = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "value") as! AnyHashable

        self.init(value)
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(value, forKey: "value")
    }
}
```

Now this SMState class is like `SMState<T: Hashable>`, you can send any kinds of enum types in this SMState Class.

Then you can use this SMState Class as what you want without the Generic

```
enum A_ENUM_KEY {
    case KEY_1
    case KEY_2
} 

let stateEncodeData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: currentState)
UserDefaults.standard.set(stateEncodeData, forKey: "state")
```

In this case, currentState is of type SMState, and SMState.value is SomeEnum, because Any Enums are **AnyHashable**

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same issue. The app crashes when calling archivedData with the following error: 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: : unrecognized selector sent to instance'"

Answer (score 0):

To address "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: : unrecognized selector sent to instance", make sure the superclass of the class you are trying to archive also extends NSCoder.